# Rspec ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

Im trying to write test on the post action of a comments controller but keep getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: @comment = @outlet.comments.build(comment_params)

     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Outlet(#70273695598160) expected, got String(#70273689026640)
```

I've tried to change some things around in the test but keep getting the same error. Not sure what else to try

Here is my test:

```
describe 'create' do
        context 'with valid attributes' do 
            before :each do
                @outlet = FactoryGirl.create(:outlet)
                @outlet_id = @outlet.id
                @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
                @user_id = @user.id
                @comment_params =  { body: "This is a comment", outlet: @outlet_id, user: @user_id } 
            end

            let(:create) { post :create, params: { outlet_id: @outlet_id, user_id: @user_id, comment: @comment_params } }

            it "creates new comment" do
                puts @outlet.class
                puts @user.class
                expect { create }.to change { Comment.count }.by 1
            end
        end
    end
```

Here is my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
        @outlet = Outlet.find(params[:outlet_id])
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @comment = @outlet.comments.build(comment_params)

        if @comment.save!
            redirect_to(@outlet)
        end
    end


    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :outlet, :user)
    end
end
```

Comment: can you put a breakpoint before the failing line and inspect what the `comment_params` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You pass in user and outlet *ids*, but you named them just `outlet` and `user` in the params.

Change your test to:

```
describe 'create' do
  context 'with valid attributes' do 
    let(outlet) { FactoryGirl.create(:outlet) }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    let(:create) do
      post :create, 
        params: { 
          comment: { body: 'Comment Test', user_id: user.id, outlet_id: outlet.id } 
        }        
    end

    it "creates new comment" do
      expect { create }.to change { Comment.count }.by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

And change your controller to:

```
def create
  @comment = Comments.new(comment_params)

  if @comment.save!
    redirect_to(comment.outlet)
  end
end


private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :outlet_id, :user_id)
end
```